# Golang - Duplicate Symbol when multiple libraries with same C libraries

Tags: go, build, linker-errors, cgo

When I try to build a Go program that has multiple libraries that import the same C libraries via CGO, I get `duplicate symbol` errors.

Here is some sample code

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/karalabe/usb"
    _ "github.com/trezor/trezord-go/usb"
)

func main() {
}
```

When I try to build this, I get errors like:

```
/Users/tlainevool/.asdf/installs/golang/1.14.2/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
duplicate symbol _hid_read_timeout in:
    /var/folders/5f/r8k9s56d5wbfpx5sj9d739pwnv1297/T/go-link-572074318/000002.o
    /var/folders/5f/r8k9s56d5wbfpx5sj9d739pwnv1297/T/go-link-572074318/000016.o
duplicate symbol _hid_get_feature_report in:
    /var/folders/5f/r8k9s56d5wbfpx5sj9d739pwnv1297/T/go-link-572074318/000002.o
    /var/folders/5f/r8k9s56d5wbfpx5sj9d739pwnv1297/T/go-link-572074318/000016.o
```

This is just a toy example, my actual code uses an internal library and another external one that both reference the same third-party C libraries, but I believe the solution would be the same.

Is there any way to get clang to recognize the symbols from the two different libraries as the same ones? Or have them be in different namespaces or something?

Comment: `go mod vendor` before running the script seems to solve the problem.

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. I got new errors
`vendor/github.com/trezor/trezord-go/usb/lowlevel/libusb/libusb.go:50:11: fatal error: 'os/threads_posix.c' file not found`
Seems like vendor doesn't pull all the C files needed for CGO?